# User registration page, with a defined user MODEL (MVC )

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have worked with .Net webforms before and now working on a MVC project.

I am working on creating a user registration page. I have no idea how its MODEL should look like.

See database diagram

[image: Diagram]

User registration page:

- Firstname
- LastName
- Email adress
- Subcribe newsletter ?
- Password
- Choose your city
- .....

I think I have to do this in this task:

**STEP 1**:

Populate cities dropdownList (choose your city) with data from database

**STEP 2**:

Insert users email address in `UserEmail` table and set subcribe to 0 or 1

**STEP 3**:

Save user registration data and EmailID (get from UserEmails table), CityID into `Users` table

Should I make a large MODEL , like this :

```
Public Class Registration Model
{
     Get, set:
     all USEREMAIL plugs ties
     all Users plugs ties
     all Cities plugs ties
}
```

How to start with this task in MVC?

(I know how to develop this in webforms , but MVC model confuses me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track.You're trying to create a view which let's users complete a registertion form, this view needs to use the user model and at the same type display a list of cities in a drop down which come from a different table in the database but are related to the user.

In MVC there's a concept called viewmodel, all that it is is a simple class which combines one or more models together.

Below I created a model called `SiteUser` and then another model called `SiteUserViewModel` which inherits from the user and gives us all the user properties **PLUS** an additional property we can use to populate the cities.So when we *display* the page, we will use the `SiteUserViewModel` but when we *post* to the controller to save the user in the database we will use `SiteUser`:

**Models:**

```
namespace MVCTutorial.Models
{
    public class SiteUser
    {
        [Display(Name="First Name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Subscribe To Newsletter?")]
        public bool SubscribeToNewsletter { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [Display(Name="City")]
        public int CityId { get; set; }
    }

    public class SiteUserViewModel : SiteUser
    {
        public List<SelectListItem> Cities { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public class SiteUserController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new SiteUserViewModel();

        //Replace this with logic that reads cities from the database
        var city1 = new SelectListItem { Text = "Johannesburg", Value = "1" };
        var city2 = new SelectListItem { Text = "Cape Town", Value = "2" };

        model.Cities = new List<SelectListItem> { city1, city2 };
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateUser(SiteUser user)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
        //Write the code to add user to the database
        return View();
    }
}
```

**View:**

```
@model MVCTutorial.Models.SiteUserViewModel

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Create User</title>
</head>
<body>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("CreateUser", "SiteUser"))
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Site User</legend>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmailAddress)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmailAddress)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmailAddress)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SubscribeToNewsletter)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SubscribeToNewsletter)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SubscribeToNewsletter)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CityId)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
               @Html.DropDownList("CityId", Model.Cities, "Please select one")
            </div>
            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Create" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>
    }
</body>
</html>
```

**Result:**
[image: Using view model in MVC]

[image: Posting a model in MVC]

Comment: Thanks Denis,


It sounds really interesting. But dont you think that it can creat  a problem later.

If I initially create an object of SiteUserViewModel and populate  it with cities data from the database. This means that SietUser propperties is NULL .

But when a user have field Registration page and press Submit button...then SiteUser pproperties should NOT be empty or NULL.
So I must put [ Required ] on all SiteUser properties !!

Comment: Yes, you can do that.I don't know what the exact requirements are.I gave you a working solution and it's up to you to tweak it and get it working exactly how you want